# Synchronize tool settings between mouse and tablet

Tags: gimp, drawing-tablet

I am trying to use a drawing tablet with Gimp. But it appears each tool has a different setting for mouse and tablet, so say if you adjusted the brush size for the tablet it's not changed for the mouse. Is there some way to change the tool settings for both mouse and tablet, so that it's possible to use both of them without hassle while working on an image.

Answer (score 3):

The right option is in `Edit -> Preferences -> Input Devices` settings page called `Share tool and tool options between input devices`

[image]

Comment: This was a lifesaver, thanks! Confirmed to be working in the Linux build of 2.10.22.

Answer (score 0):

Not what I see in 2.8 or 2.10. Tools options are the same **for a given tool** whatever the input device (ie, the brush is the same size, between mouse and tablet).

However, the brush may not be the same shape/size between two different tools (brush and pencil, for instance), and you can have  different tools associated to mouse and tablet. You can ask Gimp to share tool options between paint tools, see `Edit>Preferences>Tool options>Paint options shared between tools`